# What is the efficient way to shallow clone an object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, shallow-copy, shallow-clone

```
//function for creating a shallow object and remove the multiple spaces
export const getTrimmedValues = (values) => {
  const shallowValues = {
    ...values,
  };
  for (const key in shallowValues.primaryInformation) {
    const currentValue = shallowValues.primaryInformation[key];
    if (typeof currentValue === 'string') {
      shallowValues.primaryInformation[key] = currentValue.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
    }
  }
  return shallowValues;
};


//Original Object
const values = {
    otherObject: {}
    otherArray: []
    primaryInformation: {
        email: "test.test@testdata.com"
        externalId: "DSB-External test"
        firstName: "Dave External test    test"
        isGood: true
        isHeaven: false
        lastName: "Bacay External"
        userId: 656555
    }
}

//calling the function
getTrimmedValues(values)
```

I want to create a shallow object from the original object and edit the string to remove the multiple spaces by using shallow object and `for` loop, I think I implemented it in a wrong way.

All advices and comments are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: There is no such term as a "shallow object" in JavaScript, as you found out in the tags. And indeed, clicking on the tags will produce a list of questions about "shallow cloning" in JavaScript. But it's not clear that you are doing a shallow clone, since you actually descend into the subobject, which would be deeper than the typical "shallowness".

Comment: You've initially tagged the question with [tag:reactjs], would [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040721/1218980) answers yours?

Answer (score 1):

Here we can take advantage of JSON.stringify function has a second parameter as a replacer function is internally iterating on every key of object.
Please check the below code.

```js
//Original Object
const values = {
  otherObject: {},
  otherArray: [],
  primaryInformation: {
      email: "dave.external@testdata.com",
      externalEmployeeId: "DSB-External test   ",
      firstName: "Dave External test    test",
      isActive: true,
      isExternal: false,
      lastName: "Bacay External",
      userId: 656555,
  }
};

function getTrimmedValues(obj) {
  let str = JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    if(typeof value === 'string') {
      return value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
    }
    return value;
  });
  return JSON.parse(str);
}
console.log(getTrimmedValues(values));
```

Comment: While it works in this case, `JSON.stringify` will fail on circular references and non-serializable values (e.g. `Set`, `Date`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, @EmileBergeron for the tip, I will keep it in the mind. Can you please tell me how we can create a circular reference in the js object? I am trying but didn't create. https://codesandbox.io/s/new-frog-0mwu5z?file=/src/index.js

Comment: `values.values = values` would throw `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.